# Why wont css gradients apply to color property?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a text color a gradient, but gradients are not working on the color property, I guess it's not supported? Would there be any alternative to make a gradient-colored text?

Comment: Can you upload an image of what you want?

Comment: That's because gradients are image values, not color values.

Comment: Please include the code that you're having trouble with in the question -- how are we supposed to help if you haven't shown us the code?

Comment: Gradients are not supported on text. As of now, only chrome supports it:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/ (Works only in chrome) If you are looking for jQuery solution, try this plugin:
http://jquery-plugins.net/gradient-text-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Do you want some thing like this ? Gradient not supported for Text, but can use some text-shadow effect for the text

```
.mygradient{
    color: red;             
    font-family: Geneva, serif;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #fff9d6;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 39px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0 rgb(231,231,231),1px 1px 0 rgb(216,216,216),2px 2px 0 rgb(202,202,202),3px 3px 0 rgb(187,187,187),4px 4px 0 rgb(173,173,173),5px 5px 0 rgb(158,158,158), 6px 6px 0 rgb(144,144,144),7px 7px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),7px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);   

}

<h1 class="mygradient">Your Text Here</h1>
```

Ref: http://www.3dcsstext.com/